# Having to use http://1/? in new Uri() in order to get NameValueCollection

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to parse `string Response` into a `NameValueCollection` as shown here:

```
public static NameValueCollection Request()
{
    // Snipped irrelevant code, so here's the string I get:
    string Response = "someparam=abcdef&another=123456";

    return HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(
        new Uri("http://1/?" + Response)
    .Query);
}

NameValueCollection Request = SomeClass.Request();
string SomeParam = Request.Get("someparam");
string Another = Request.Get("another");
```

But it seems "wrong" for me to have to specify `http://1/?` (a `UriFormatException` is thrown without it).

Is there a different way I should be approaching this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no reason for you to use `Uri` here, just `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Response)` should do.